# Does 8086 assembly language work on a modern CPU?

Tags: assembly, x86

Is the 8086 assembly language workable on intel pentium D computer?
I am learning assembly language programming from a book that talks about 8086 processor only, which is 16bit. Is the assembly language for modern processors like pentium D different?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, it will still execute the old opcodes.  Your program won't take advantage of the modern pentium facilities however, such as instruction pipelining and branch prediction.  Only code optimized for the pentium can take advantage of those facilities.

Comment: That's utterly false. While you can optimize to improve the efficacy of branch prediction and pipelining, it'll still be used in executing older code. What you can't use would be things like the larger (32-bit) registers, or newer (MMX/SSE/SSE2/etc.) instruction sets.

Comment: @Jerry I stand corrected, I always assumed the Pentium wouldn't use pipelining or branch prediction on older 16 bit 8086 instructions - I thought it had a virtual execution mode which was single pipeline but I might be remembering two different processors - my old memory does that at times :P

Comment: @Jerry: you can use the larger registers and address space if you use the size override prefixes.

Answer (score 3):

this is what I learnt since I asked this question. Assembly language is always ISA specific. x86 assembly language is the family of the assembly languages for the x86 processors. Intel first introduced x86 ISA in 1978. that was meant for a 16-bit processor. Later as Intel developed new processors with wider data buses, new features and instructions were added in x86 ISA at every stage. so with the evolution of x86 processor, assembly language that is used to program, also expanded and developed. since I am learning assembly language from a book that talks about 8086 processor only, i would not come to know the new features and new instructions of more advance x86 processors. programs of 8086 assembly language would work on even most modern x86 family processor due to backward compatibility, which is a boon and equally a curse..

Comment: The above is NOT CORRECT - programs of 8086 assembly language DO NOT work on modern x86 processors. To use 16-bit (8086) assembly language, you have to assemble and link a DOS program and run it on an OS that supports DOS emulation.

Answer (score 2):

Modern processors support 32-bit assembly language, which has some differences. To use 16-bit (8086) assembly language, you'll have to assemble and link a DOS program (and run it on an OS that supports DOS emulation, such as 32-bit Windows XP).

Comment: Even more modern processors support 64 bit opcodes and 64 bit addresses :P.

Comment: It's not really the numeric version of Windows that matters -- it's whether it's the 32-bit or 64-bit edition. Yes, once you know 8086 assembly language, learning 32-bit is mostly a matter of learning which restrictions you don't have to worry about any more (and 64-bit assembly language loosens the restrictions still more).

Comment: that is what I do. I write a code, assemble it using MASM, link it and debug it on command prompt on my desktop which has 32-bit windows XP and laptop which has Windows 7.  so to learn assembly language programming on a modern x86 microprocessor, do I just need to learn 8086 assembly language plus new instructions and register-size of modern microprocessor?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its different. Especially modern processors run in protected mode instead of real mode which 8086 targets. You can instead download an emulator such as this:

http://www.emu8086.com/

Comment: I recall jumping into debug on a windows xp machine and running and old com program I had source for.  I seem to recall that pentiums have a virtual execution mode for older opcodes - otherwise you would have to rewrite every program when the cpu changes.

Comment: True, Win 7 and Vista are totally different beasts.

Comment: Just FWIW, XP-x64 doesn't have DOS emulation either.

Comment: @Madhur win 7 does have debug program. I run it from command prompt. I have this emulator. it has been very helpful at times. It confuses when I add ORG 10H directive in the code. it gives error.

Comment: I learnt that on 'loading' operating system assigns 0000H offset value to the code and data segment. it works this in the emulator but in real life when I debug the same small code from command prompt data segment offset is few bytes away from 0000H. It adds to confusion and hampers the studies when I don't see things working out the way the books say they should. FYI I'm pursuing MCA from IGNOU.

Comment: Don't go by command prompt, 8086 is vastly different from modern pentium. Use a good emulator for this purpose ...